# Is it possible to create a Rancher Project (kind: Project) via kubectl?

Tags: rancher, rancher-cli

Is it possible to create a Rancher Project (kind: Project) for example via kubectl?

I copied the YAML spec for a given project and changed the name of the project. 'kubectl apply' returns that it can not find the CRD for kind Projects.

How is this possible? The UI shows this kind of CRD but it can not be created via kubectl

Is there another option to create a project in Rancher via CLI?

Comment: I have a similar question where looking for `kubectl get projects -A` returns nothing.

Comment: However, kubectl was able to create a project from a yaml. I copied an existing project's yaml config from Rancher UI, cleaned it up using the kubectl-neat plugin, updated the name and got it to create a new project with similar configs. 

It looks like terraform might be the next best option to create project from code.

Comment: Give us a clean yaml example so we can create projects too?!